# MariaDB Row Size Limit enforced in Windows but not on Linux

Tags: mariadb

If I run the following code on Maria for Windows it fails with "ERROR 1118 (42000): Row size too large" which is fair enough given the documented limitations

```
C:\Development\YADAMU>mysql -uroot -poracle -hyadamu-db3 -P3307
mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 788
Server version: 5.5.5-10.6.4-MariaDB mariadb.org binary distribution

Copyright (c) 2000, 2021, Oracle and/or its affiliates.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql> SET AUTOCOMMIT = 0, TIME_ZONE = '+00:00',SESSION INTERACTIVE_TIMEOUT = 600000, WAIT_TIMEOUT = 600000, SQL_MODE='ANSI_QUOTES,PAD_CHAR_TO_FULL_LENGTH', GROUP_CONCAT_MAX_LEN = 1024000, GLOBAL LOCAL_INFILE = 'ON';  /* Manager */
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> --
mysql> drop table if exists "t_postgres1"."binary_types";
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.05 sec)

mysql> --
mysql> create table if not exists "t_postgres1"."binary_types"(
    ->   "bytea_col" varbinary(5),
    ->   "bool_col" tinyint(1),
    ->   "bit_col" varchar(32767),
    ->   "bit_varying_col" varchar(32767),
    ->   "bit_8_col" varchar(32767),
    ->   "bit_varying_64_col" varchar(32767)
    -> );
ERROR 1118 (42000): Row size too large. The maximum row size for the used table type, not counting BLOBs, is 65535. This includes storage overhead, check the manual. You have to change some columns to TEXT or BLOBs
mysql>
mysql> exit
Bye
```

Except for the fact that if run exactly the same SQL against a Linux instance of MariaDB, running in the latest published container, it works

```
C:\Development\YADAMU>mysql -uroot -poracle -P3307
mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 116
Server version: 5.5.5-10.6.4-MariaDB-1:10.6.4+maria~focal mariadb.org binary distribution

Copyright (c) 2000, 2021, Oracle and/or its affiliates.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql> SET AUTOCOMMIT = 0, TIME_ZONE = '+00:00',SESSION INTERACTIVE_TIMEOUT = 600000, WAIT_TIMEOUT = 600000, SQL_MODE='ANSI_QUOTES,PAD_CHAR_TO_FULL_LENGTH', GROUP_CONCAT_MAX_LEN = 1024000, GLOBAL LOCAL_INFILE = 'ON';  /* Manager */
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> --
mysql> drop table if exists "t_postgres1"."binary_types";
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)

mysql> --
mysql> create table if not exists "t_postgres1"."binary_types"(
    ->   "bytea_col" varbinary(5),
    ->   "bool_col" tinyint(1),
    ->   "bit_col" varchar(32767),
    ->   "bit_varying_col" varchar(32767),
    ->   "bit_8_col" varchar(32767),
    ->   "bit_varying_64_col" varchar(32767)
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 4 warnings (0.03 sec)

mysql>
mysql>
```

What am I missing here ?

Comment: What does `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'default_storage_engine'` show in each of the instances?

Comment: INNODB in both cases...

Comment: Looking at the entire output of show variables the biggest difference I could see is the language settings.. The Docker Image (Linux) is using  utf8mb4, and the windows image is using latin1. I need to have Unicode on both so I'll workout how to get my windows image character set switched and try again.. I sort of hope that isn't the cause of this.....

Comment: It was a bug, see: https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MCOL-713

Comment: the error was mentioned in the release notes of 5.5.28a, see: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb-5528a-changelog/    "Revision #2661.817.81 Fri 2012-08-31 15:42:00 +0530
Bug #13453036 ERROR CODE 1118: ROW SIZE TOO LARGE - EVEN THOUGH IT IS NOT."

Comment: @Luuk Thanks for this. Unfortunately given that I'm running with the 'latest' download from Maria, the fix for the issue you identified was resolved in 2019, I'm not sure that the issue you identified is the cause of the issue I'm seeing.

Answer (score 0):

Well thanks go to @[sticky bit] for pointing me in the right direction and forcing me to see that I had different character sets defined. Once I switched the Windows version to "utf8mb4" the statement works in both instances.

I'm not sure I want to ask why at this point, since this allows me to continue Windows Regression testing...